# Sending and Displaying HTML With HTTP Headers

Tags: python, html, http, wsgi, gunicorn

I am learning a few things about HTTP protocol and am trying to write a basic WSGI app in Python. I installed `gunicorn` WSGI server and got a basic "Hello World" to work.

However, I am still wondering how I can display actual HTML on the page. That is, how do I include HTML in my response?

Example:

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    """Simplest possible application object"""
    data = b'<html> Hello, World!\n </html>'
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [
        ('Content-type','text/plain'),
        ('Content-Length', str(len(data)))
    ]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return iter([data])
```

Comment: You should consider using a WSGI framework that handles this for you rather than attempting to use raw WSGI. Have a look at Flask (flask.pocoo.org) as a simple WSGI framework that will make your life much easier.

Comment: Yes. However, I want to avoid those precisely because I want to learn the low-level HTTP :)

Comment: Use Flask first to understand at high level how things work, then drop down and look at how Flask is implemented to understand it better. Flask internally uses a component library for WSGI called Werkzeug. You can also read https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbaws-part1/